# If datepicker already has value run onselect anyway

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Currently, I can select a date and it fills my input fields with the date for 7 days and the corresponding day of the week in another series on input fields (just 3 days in example below).  This is working well, although I'm sure there is a more efficient way to write the same thing with arrays, I just have no idea.

However, if I get the start date from the database on page load rather than selecting it with datepicker, it obviously doesn't trigger the onselect event and the fields don't populate.  How can I get it to populate the fields in both situations?

I was thinking a function that is run when either the datepicker input has a valid value or onselect, but having never really touched JS before this little project I'm in over my head.

```
$(function() {
$("#StartDate").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  onSelect: function(dateStr, inst) {
      var weekday=new Array(7);
        weekday[0]="Monday";
        weekday[1]="Tuesday";
        weekday[2]="Wednesday";
        weekday[3]="Thursday";
        weekday[4]="Friday";
        weekday[5]="Saturday";
        weekday[6]="Sunday";
      var Date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateStr);
      Date1.setDate(Date1.getDate('dd/mm/yy'));
      $('#Date1').val(Date1.toLocaleDateString());
      $('#Day1').val(weekday[Date1.getUTCDay()]);
      var Date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateStr);
      Date2.setDate(Date2.getDate('dd/mm/yy') + 1);
      $('#Date2').val(Date2.toLocaleDateString());
      $('#Day2').val(weekday[Date2.getUTCDay()]);
      var Date3 = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateStr);
      Date3.setDate(Date3.getDate('dd/mm/yy') + 2);
      $('#Date3').val(Date3.toLocaleDateString());
      $('#Day3').val(weekday[Date3.getUTCDay()]);
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a loop like this?

```
$(function() {
$("#StartDate").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  onSelect: function(dateStr, inst) {
      var weekday=new Array(7);
        weekday[0]="Monday";
        weekday[1]="Tuesday";
        weekday[2]="Wednesday";
        weekday[3]="Thursday";
        weekday[4]="Friday";
        weekday[5]="Saturday";
        weekday[6]="Sunday";

      for(i=0;i<weekday.length;i++){
        var Date = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateStr);
        Date.setDate(Date.getDate('dd/mm/yy') + i);             // "i" is the array index 
        $('#Date').val(Date.toLocaleDateString());
        $('#Day').val(weekday[Date.getUTCDay()]);
      }
  });
});
```

---

**EDIT** --- I misunderstood the question.

So here is another try, since I'm still unsure to get it... But getting closer.

If `#startDate` is already populated onload, you wish to run the above script as if it was selected using the datepicker, right?

So assuming something like this, on PHP side, to fill the `StartDate` field:
 `<input type="text" id="startDate" value="<?php echo $date; ?>"></input>`

I would get this function out of the datepicker `init` to be able to run it from elsewhere.
I've done a [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/OpwzLY) to test this.

```
// This is the function you had on select
var DayFill = function(dateStr, inst) {

  var weekday=new Array(7);
  weekday[0]="Monday";
  weekday[1]="Tuesday";
  weekday[2]="Wednesday";
  weekday[3]="Thursday";
  weekday[4]="Friday";
  weekday[5]="Saturday";
  weekday[6]="Sunday";

  for(i=0;i<weekday.length;i++){
    var Date = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateStr);
    Date.setDate(Date.getDate('dd/mm/yy') + i);             // "i" is the array index 
    $('#Date'+i).val(Date.toLocaleDateString());

    // Fix day number to fit the array index
    var daynum = Date.getUTCDay()-1;
    if(daynum==-1){
      daynum=6;
    }

    $('#Day'+i).val(weekday[daynum]);
  }
}

// This is your datepicker init
$("#StartDate").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  onSelect: DayFill         // Call the FillDay function, now out of this init.
});

// Onload, run the DayFill function using the input value
$(document).ready(function(){
  DayFill( $("#StartDate").val() );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  If I'm not mistaken you're not answering my main question but rather you're giving an example of how to simplify my currently working code, is that correct?  How would I then add the relevant date to each <input>?  Because right now I have #Date1, #Day1, and so on until #Date7, #Day7.

Comment: I clearly misunderstood the question... But hold on.

Comment: I just "improved" my answer... See if it better suits your need. ;)

Comment: I know it says this comment section is not for giving thanks but screw that... This is like magic to me, thank you very much for taking the time to help!  I'm going to study this solution, it will really help me to better understand how functions work. Thank you, you've been so helpful! =)